# Setting up cloudinary and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, cloudinary

I used the paperclip gem to upload images onto my app. Now I'm trying to deploy to Heroku and want to use Cloudinary to host the images. I followed the documentation and added my cloudinary.yml file into my config directory. Even locally when I add this my images disappear

this works locally:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100" }
```

Adding the commands for cloudinary makes all my images disappear:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100" },:storage => :cloudinary,
  :path => ':id/:style/:filename'
```

If I try to push to heroku it also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked this documentation?
 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary#using-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: "I followed the documentation" - Please add a link to that